# jQuery Datepicker links not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, url, hyperlink, datepicker

I'm using Datepicker in my web site as a program. What I need is for each day of the calendar to lead to a different page. So far urls are great, but links not so much. On click nothing happens. I can open the links in new tab/window with right click but I need them to work in the current tab.

Is there a default setting for this somewhere? I made a little demo for myself with only Datepicker to check if it's something else causing the problem, but it's not. Am I missing something here? I've searched and searched through the JS but came short handed. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Here's what I'm using to display it
`<div id="calendar"></div>`

And that's how it looks like (title and weekdays are in Bulgarian)
[image]

What I need to happen is when I click, let's say, 10th, to redirect me to another page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it in javascript using the datepicker's widget event

Documentation is here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Here is the javascript example:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function(string){
       // Note that the string variable would return the selected date
       console.log(string);
       window.location = "http://localhost/page?date=" + string

    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand how that function works... Would you elaborate, please?

Comment: We're thinking about different things. I don't need the date, I've edited my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: I swear we're thinking about the same thing... let me update my code a little bit and you,ll understand (i hope)

Comment: Okay, but that's gonna open the same page every time. I need each number to have a different href (as opposed to # like its by default). The hrefs are like http://{localhost}/page?&date={date}/{month}/{year}.

Comment: Well yes, that's why I gave you the variable string (that is the date). you need to program the rest but you have everything you need there. You just have to take the string, split it, catch the date month and year and then apply the variable at the right place in the adress you're doing the redirection

Comment: Did it for you now, you have everything you need the way you want, enjoy